# How to pass the params from JS to rails3 controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Here is my JS.coffee codes:

```
fetchselect =(val) ->
 $.ajax(url: '/firstpages/page', dataType: 'json', par_id: val )

$('.homeNav').find('.unactive').click ->
 id = $(this).attr('id')
 fetchselect(id)
```

and Here is my controller codes:

```
def page
@select = Firstpage.where(:pid=>params[:par_id])

 respond_to do |format|
   format.html # page.html.erb
   format.js { render :layout => false }
   format.json { render :json => @select }
end
```

end
It can't pass the params to @select ,when I click $('.homeNav') ,the log tell me:

Started GET "/firstpages/page" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-07 05:27:07 +0800
Processing by FirstpagesController#page as JSON
  Firstpage Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "firstpages".* FROM "firstpages" WHERE "firstpages"."pid" IS NULL
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in the actual ajax request. Try:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/firstpages/page',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {par_id : val})
})
```

For more examples, check out the [jQuery $.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server).

Comment: It's OK,but can't achieve the Ajax,the log tell me:Started GET "/firstpages/page?par_id=nb" I want "/firstpages/page"

Comment: If you don't want the params in the url, then you'll need to perform a POST request. I'll add that to my original answer. When you say "can't achieve the Ajax"...is that because of a javaScript error or a Rails routing error?